# Convert Table into Matrix in SQL

Tags: db2

I have this table of favorite foods (called "food_table") - notice that there is no information for (burger, burger):

```
    food_1    food_2 number_of_people
     pizza     pizza                3
 chocolate     pizza                3
     tacos     pizza               10
    burger     pizza                2
     pizza chocolate                6
 chocolate chocolate                5
     tacos chocolate                4
    burger chocolate                6
     pizza     tacos                9
 chocolate     tacos               10
     tacos     tacos                5
    burger     tacos                3
     pizza    burger                9
 chocolate    burger                9
     tacos    burger                9
```

I am trying to make a 4x4 matrix which shows the relative percentages of people that like each combination:

```
# step 1: counts (food1 , food2)

               pizza chocolate tacos burger

 pizza         3         6     9      9
 chocolate     3         5    10      9
 tacos        10         4     5      9
 burger      NULL        6     3      3

# step 2 :precents (each row should add to 100)
(food1 , food2)
e.g. (pizza,pizza) = 3/(3+6+9+9), (pizza,chocolate) = 6/(3+6+9+9), (pizza,tacos) = 9/(3+6+9+9), (pizza,burger) = 9/(3+6+9+9)

             pizza chocolate    tacos   burger
pizza     11.11111  22.22222 33.33333 33.33333
chocolate 11.11111  18.51852 37.03704 33.33333
tacos     35.71429  14.28571 17.85714 32.14286
burger    NULL       50       25       25
```

I tried like this:

```
with step1 as (
select
 food_1, 
food_2,
 number_of_people * 100/ sum(number_of_people) over (partition by food_1) as percent
from food_table
group by 
food_1, 
food_2),

step2 as(
select food_1 as "food1/food2",
max(case when food_2 = 'pizza' then percent end) as pizza,
max(case when food_2 = 'tacos' then percent end) as tacos,
max(case when food_2 = 'burger' then percent end) as burger,
max(case when food_2 = 'chocolate' then percent end) as chocolate
from step1
group by "food1/food2")

select * from step2;
```

But I dont think this is correct - the results of the code are not matching my hand calculations.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your table shown is not correct - burger & pizza cannot be NULL as there is a 2 listed above.

Secondly your SQL in step 1 uses an OLAP function and does not need the GROUP BY. by.

Try this modified SQL

```
 with step1 as (
select
 food_1, 
food_2,
 number_of_people * 100/ sum(number_of_people) over (partition by food_1) as percent
from food
)
, step2 as(
select food_1 as "food1/food2",
max(case when food_2 = 'pizza' then percent end) as pizza,
max(case when food_2 = 'tacos' then percent end) as tacos,
max(case when food_2 = 'burger' then percent end) as burger,
max(case when food_2 = 'chocolate' then percent end) as chocolate
from step1
group by food_1)

select * from step2;
```

It does not add to 100 because of rounding - so you might want to change the data type to decimal.